# Diccionario y herencia en POO Python

Tags: python

Necesito saber cómo usar un diccionario dentro de `class Personal_Universitario`, que contenga características de las personas que trabajan dentro de una universidad.

Además, debo crear las clases `class Oficina`, `class Profesor` y ``` class Alumno``, que hereden todas las características de ``` class Personal_Universitario```.

Por otro lado, en el caso de `class Oficina` debe añadir al diccinario el dato `Puesto`. En el caso de `class Profesor`, debe añadir al diccionario `Especialización`, y por último en el caso de `class Alumno`, debe añadir al diccionario el dato `Creditos_Aprobados` que debe ser un número entero.

```
class Personal_Universitario:
        
        def __init__(self):
            self.atributo = {
                id_:None
                nombre:None
                email:None
            }
        
       
class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):
    Personal_Universitario[puesto]=None
```

Comment: Antes de todo, que has intentado? que has logrado? muestra algun avance de codigo para que podamos ayudarte, no hacemos tareas, revisa en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3583/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-preguntas-de-manera-correcta-y-evitar-que-te-la-cierren

Comment: class Personal_Universitario:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.atributo = {
            id_:None
            nombre:None
            email:None
        }
    
   
class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):
    Personal_Universitario[puesto]=None

Comment: Bienvenidx Lleipi. Te da algún error el código? O no sabes como continuar? Cual sería tu duda?

Comment: podrias agregarlo a la pregunta, para poder verlo mejor 
un atajo si pegas tu codigo, selecciona todo y preciona ctrl+k para que te de formato

Comment: me da error tipo nombre no definido, y al no pasar de ese parametro no continua el codigo.

Comment: @ChristianGtz he modificado la publicacion, gracias por recordame esa funcion.

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: no es toma mi tarea y hazlo al contrario hubo un usuario que dio perfectamente su ayuda y desde alli he aprendido y he podido seguir avanzando. No todo es normas muchas veces es mas empatia y ayudar de verdad al que esta empezando porque sino no entiendo para que existe este sitio @gbianchi

Comment: Pues si que lo es. No hay una sola demostracion que intentaste siquiera plantear el ejercicio. Esta pregunta y respuesta solo te sirve a vos, y no demuestra un problema real, solo el enunciado del ejercicio sin demostrar que intentaste hacer algo para resolverlo, aunque estuviera mal, y de esa forma poder explicarte tus errores.

Comment: Aloha~ vengo a colaborar: Lectura recomendada https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 (hay un video dentro que me encantaría que vean) espero les sea de utilidad :D

Comment: gracias @fredyf, he mirado tu lectura y video recomendado; voy conociendo mas de como funciona por aquí las cosas. Totalmente nuevo y en apuros con esto de programar.

Comment: Descuida, es cosa de practicar, entender la sintaxis, básicamente la programación se resume en 4 cosas: declarar variables, asignarles valores, leer valores, leer los errores. Las preguntas que se reciben con grandes ojos cumplen esa lista mencionada en el enlace, algunos usuarios lo toman para bien. Éxitos y bienvenido al mundo de la programación :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lleipi, antes que nada, me parece que te convendría repasar un poco Programación Orientada a Objetos. Te dejo acá un curso donde te explica detalladamente todo lo relacionado con POO: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU8oAlHdN5BlvPxziopYZRd55pdqFwkeS . Es muy bueno, saltéate lo que ya sabes, y ve directo a POO.

También te dejo un código que te soluciona el inconveniente. Ten en cuenta que no te sirve de nada solo copiar y pegar el código. Tomate tu tiempo para ir paso por paso en cada línea de código, y entender bien qué hace cada cosa. Cualquier duda puedes preguntar en comentarios. Saludos.

Fíjate que el diccionario lo creo por fuera de la clase, y luego lo utilizo dentro de la función (que está dentro de la clase), y para poder utilizar una variable que está afuera, utilizas el método ```global dictionario````.

Además, dentro de la clase `class Oficina`, utilizo la función super, que facilita heredar múltiples variables.

```
dictionario = {}

class Personal_Universitario:
    
    def __init__(self, Id, nombre, email):
        self.Id = Id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.email = email
    
    def descripcion(self):
        global dictionario
        dictionario["ID"] = self.Id
        dictionario["Nombre"] = self.nombre
        dictionario["Email"] = self.email
        



class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):

    def __init__(self, puesto, Id_oficina, nombre_oficina, email_oficina):

        super().__init__(Id_oficina, nombre_oficina, email_oficina)

        self.puesto = puesto

    def descripcion(self):
        global dictionario
        
        super().descripcion()

        dictionario["Puesto"] = self.puesto

        print(dictionario)

        

oficina1 = Oficina("Admin", 1, "Esteban", "esteban@gmail.com")

oficina1.descripcion()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo @ariel berinstein; seguire tu recomendacion ya que si me veo un poco confundido me esta costando mucho realizar la logica de los problemas, probare tambien el codigo que recomiendas.

Comment: De nada @Lleipi . Acuérdate de marcar como correcta mi respuesta si te sirvió, me ayuda a crecer a mi también, gracias.

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Siempre sé educado y diviértete
Está bien si no estás de acuerdo o si expresas preocupación, pero compórtate bien. Hay un ser humano al otro lado de la pantalla, no importa lo equivocado que parezca. Estamos aquí para aprender de nuestros colegas, no para gritarnos el uno al otro.

Comment: @gbianchi justamente por eso le dije que cualquier duda que tenga me pueda preguntar, de cualquier manera, ahi edite el codigo para que entienda mejor algunas cosas.

Comment: Tu respuesta no es solo para quien pregunta.. es para el y para todos los que la lean despues. por eso, se pide que la respuesta sea completa